# different method when install php

Tags: php

I want to install LNMP(Linux, Nginx, php and MySql) on my ubuntu.

I googled,but I found severals diff methods for installing php although they all used apt-get.

This made me doubt.

Some one used:

```
apt-get install php5
```

Some one used:

```
apt-get install php5-pfm
```

and some one used:

```
apt-get install php5-common php5-cli php5-fpm
```

I do not know the diff of these methods, can some one tell me?

Comment: Cant you use google to lookup those packages?

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/php5 and http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/php5-fpm - see the dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following:

1. update apt-get

   sudo apt-get update
2. Install MySQL

   sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
3. Install nginx

   sudo apt-get install nginx

   sudo service nginx start

   ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }'
4. Install PHP

   sudo apt-get install php5-fpm

PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) is an alternative PHP FastCGI implementation with some additional features. This is used for busier sites. If you want you can use that too or go for simple php5 install

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Synaptic Package Manager** if you do not know the exact way of installing.
It's easy to use and you do not need to worry about all the dependency packages.

Eg:

Once you selected the php5 module, package manager selects the required dependencies.

If you don not have "Synaptic Package Manager" installed use the following command.

sudo apt-get install synaptic